# Tracking ERC20 token movements

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I'm creating a tool to track ERC20 token movements. My assumption is that tokens moves or via `transfer` or `transferFrom` function. The first one is the first spreading of the token, the other one when the token is transferred from an owner to another.
Is this assumption correct?
Apparently with a few experiment I did I can see just the `transfer` call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is not quite correct. Both functions move tokens. `transfer` moves them from the author of the transaction to the specified receiver. `transferFrom` moves them from the specified sender to the specified receiver (provided the transaction author is allowed to do so).

In order to track token movements, you should listen to the `Transfer` events that are specified in the ERC20 standard:

```
Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)
```